# Filling DS160 (B2) for a person (from India) who doesn't have proof of education

Tags: usa, india, b2visa

While filling the DS-160 form for B2 visa, I came across a question : Have you attended any educational institutions at a secondary level or above?

My mother has completed her graduation during the 1960-1970s but she does not have any proof of the same currently. Will it be a problem during the interview in case the interviewer asks for proof? (if it is mentioned)

Or is it safe to mention 'No' to this question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Never lie to in immigration officer, also no in filling out forms. Best answer 'yes but no proof' if you can.

Comment: I would be mightily surprised if anybody asked for proof of someone having graduated 50 years ago. Just say yes.

Answer (score 9):

Your mother *did* graduate secondary school, so the truthful answer to this question is **Yes**.

If she went to secondary school in the 1960s, I presume your mother is long retired.  And since you're applying for a B2 visa, I presume she is coming for a social visit, not employment, business, training etc.  These combined make it *very* unlikely that she would be asked for proof of graduation during the interview: it's simply not relevant for this kind of visa, and due to her age she is not considered high risk for illegally working in the US.

Nevertheless, if she is asked, she should simply truthfully state that this was over 50 years ago and she has lost the papers.  This is entirely reasonable and is highly unlikely to cause issues.